# Value based on whether a column equals a constant

Tags: if, column

I have a list of values "New, Pending, Confirmed" and columns: date and details. I would like to calculate:

> x= IF details="New" THEN get(date)

> y= IF details="Pending" THEN get(date)

THEN in a new column, SUBTRACT **y-x** to see how long it took for date to go to "Pending" from "New"

Comment: Is this in excel? What have you tried? Have you looked up the IF and SWITCH functions?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to clarify in what language and program this is? Also please add the relevant tags.